# In Unity/C#, my values aren't stored anymore after I start an IEnumerator that sends HTTP request

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, httprequest

Basically, I have a method that stores certain static variables when I click a button. This button calls a HTTP request as well as changes a scene.

The button calls a coroutine as so `StartCoroutine(Post(currURI, bodyJsonString));`. The Post method is an IEnumerator as so

```
IEnumerator Post(string url, string bodyJsonString)
    {
        var request = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST");
        byte[] bodyRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bodyJsonString);
        request.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler)new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
        request.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler)new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
        request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        Debug.Log("**************************************");

        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        Debug.Log("Status Code: " + request.responseCode);
        Debug.Log("Status Code: " + request.downloadHandler.text);

        string myResponse = request.downloadHandler.text;

        var welcome = Welcome.FromJson(myResponse);
        Debug.Log("welcome " + welcome);
        CurrPower.numberColorBombs = welcome.Marbles.Count(n => n.Nickname.ToLower() == "Corkscrew Swirl".ToLower());
        CurrPower.myPowerups[0] = CurrPower.numberColorBombs;

        Debug.Log("power " + CurrPower.myPowerups[0]);
    }
```

All I see in the console is `******************` and it doesn't reach the other lines logs as the request isn't processed. Perhaps this has to do with the scene switching? If so, I guess I need to make the call after the scene switches or set a timer.

UPDATE: I solved this by putting the request into another function, so it has time to wait before changing scenes. Now the problem is getting it to successfully send on Android. I will try to use `WWWForm` as @TimChang suggested

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's waiting for the request to complete. Are you sure that the remote host has completed the request in the time you let it run with the console only showing `******************`?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html
`UnityWebRequest.Post` try that ?

Comment: Why don't you wait with switching the scene until the upload is done?

Answer (score 1):

In the end of the document https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

It says:

> Coroutines are not stopped when a MonoBehaviour is disabled, but only **when it is definitely destroyed**.

When you change the scene, the gameobject may be destroyed, so the coroutine stops.

You can start the coroutine on a global gameobject (Object.DontDestroyOnLoad), or change the scene after it finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Extending on [shingo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57797848/7111561)

> If so, I guess I need to make the call after the scene switches or set a timer.

You could indeed also simply wait until the upload is done and switch your scene after that. E.g. using

```
IEnumerator Post(string url, string bodyJsonString, Action whenDone)
{
    ...

    whenDone?.Invoke();
}
```

And now you can define a callback that executed after the upload e.g. as lambda expression like

```
StartCoroutine(Post(currURI, bodyJsonString, () =>
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(XY);
    }
));
```

Or as method call like e.g.

```
StartCoroutine(Post(currURI, bodyJsonString, LoadTheScene));

...

private void LoadTheScene()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(XY);
}
```